# jquery CSS multiple values for background size

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is my code,

```
$('#snapContainer').css({"background-size": "95%", "cover !important",
"min-height": "100%",
"position": "relative",
"left": "2%",
"margin-bottom": "15%",
"display": "inline-block"});
```

background-size values are not getting. whats the possible error?

Comment: `"background-size": "95%", "cover !important",` that is invalid object

Comment: Also better to use addClass & remevoClass methods rather than inline css, since inline css has highest precedance in css

Answer (score 1):

See [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Try removing comma `,` , substituting percentage value for "cover"

```
/* where `95%` is `width` , `100%` is `height` */
"background-size": "95% 100% !important"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error on your code, it should be like this "background-size" : "95%, cover !important"

```
$('#snapContainer').css({"background-size": "95%, cover !important",
"min-height": "100%",
"position": "relative",
"left": "2%",
"margin-bottom": "15%",
"display": "inline-block"});
```

Comment: are you sure `95% cover !important` is a valid `background-size` value

Comment: missing comma :  "95%, cover!important"

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But code is not working. same issue.

Comment: I miss a comma, did you check that

Comment: I did check, but the background-size properties are not setting .

Comment: @ArunPJohny : Yes it is valid value